# Django: How to filter model objects after passing through functions?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model called `Service`, which has a field `url` of type `str`. I have a function `f` that returns the hostname of an url:

```
def f(url):
    return urllib.parse.urlparse(url).hostname
```

I want to get all the objects whose `f(url)` equals a value `target`.

One way to achieve this would be by doing the following:

```
[x for x in Service.objects.all() if(f(x.url) == target)]
```

But in that case, I'll get a `list`, not a `QuerySet`.

Is there a way to filter the objects and get a `QuerySet` satisfying the above criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try sthg like this instead of looping through, we are changing target:

```
from django.db.models import Q

target_not_safe = 'http://'+target
target_safe = 'https://'+target
queryset = Service.objects.filter(Q(url=target_not_safe) | Q(url=target_safe))
```

[Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

#### EDIT

How about using [`_istartwith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith):

```
queryset = Service.objects.filter(Q(url__istartswith=target_not_safe) | Q(url__istartswith=target_safe))
```

#### Edit 2

Another trick could be to check inside the list using [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in). So:

```
query_list = [x.id for x in Service.objects.all() if(f(x.url) == target)]
queryset = Service.objects.filter(id__in=query_list)
```

Comment: That would work only if `url` contains either `http://something.com` or `https://something.com`, right? It won't work if url contains `http://something.com/a/b/c/d`, right? But my requirement is that it should take those objects into consideration as well.

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya what do think about using `startswith`?

Comment: I think that should work for most of the cases, but doesn't sound like a robust solution, right? Multiple URLs might start with the same hostname.

Basically, is there no way to translate this simple query to Django: `select something from somewhere where f(someVar) = someOtherVar`, where`f` is a custom function?

Comment: Yes... obviously is somekind of trick.... What do you mean by "*Multiple URLs might start with the same hostname.*". Your method will also give the  same output as it still if you have the same host, not???

Comment: By that I meant, suppose there are two websites: first one has hostname `a.b.c`, the other has hostname `a.b.c.d` or `a.b.cd`. In that case, `startsWith` will come `True`, which won't satisfy the requirement. The `__in` solution looks good, I'll go with that one. Thanks.